# window.frames['myframe'] gives me an error in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window.frames['myframe'].document.getElementById('frameid'))
```

This statement sometimes returns `null` in `Firefox` but working properly in any other browsers. What can be the problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I have many frames on the page. If something occurs on the page I am trying to trigger an event by finding related frame and the button in that frame to fire it. However, sometimes firefox could not find the frame. The statement on above returns null. Thats my problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: ... example please. Use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it you simply need to change the selector it should be

```
$('#myframe').contents().find('#frameid').html();
```

JQuery handles the finding of it, take a look at selectors in jQuery
[Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: I have tried this but it also returns sometimes null but thanks

Comment: Does this really cascade into other frames? I don't think that it does.

Comment: I did a bit more searching and you may be right however i will submit a modification